# Por cada 'OUT' que este en el array tengo que sacar el primer numero, Pero me debuelve un array vacio

Tags: javascript, array, queue

El array de movimientos tendrá la siguiente forma:

```
[23, 43, "OUT", 65, "OUT", 32, 55, "OUT"]
```

donde cada número representa el ingreso
de un vehículo al que se le asigna dicho valor; y cada "OUT" representa la salida
del vehículo que lleva más tiempo dentro del estacionamiento.
Finalmente, la función debe retornar la QUEUE que representa el estado del estacionamiento
al momento de finalizar los eventos del array.

REQUISITOS:

La función debe retornar la QUEUE resultante de procesar los movimientos.

Si la función intenta retirar un vehículo cuando la Queue se encuentra vacía, debe retornar false

ATENCIÓN! La QUEUE que retorna la función debe ser una instancia de la clase QUEUE.

```
function henryParking(arr) {    
  let newqueue = new Queue(); 
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      if (arr[i]=== "OUT" && newqueue["array"].length === 0) {
        return false; 
      }
        if(arr[i] === "OUT" &&  newqueue[arr[i]].length === 'Number'){
          newqueue.shift(arr[i])          
        }
        return newqueue;    
  }  
  henryParking();
}
```

Comment: aun no consigo en que error estoy en el jsrum si me funcionaba , creo que estoy haciendo algo mal con intanciar la queue, nesecito comprencion en esto .

Comment: No se entiende cuál es tu pregunta. Qué problema tienes con este código y ese enunciado? Ve a [edit] y explícalo en detalle, por favor

Comment: [23, 43, "OUT", 65, "OUT", 32, 55, "OUT"]  el problema es que por cada 'OUT' que esta el array tengo que sacar el primer numero osea quedaria [32, 55, ] pero me debuelve un array vacion .  
@Alfabravo

Comment: El problematica que se plantea es de Queue , por eso hice una instancia de la clase QUEUE.

Answer (score 0):

Queue no está definido en js ¿Podrías indicar de donde lo sacas?

Las colas no están hechas para hacer esto

```
newqueue.shift(arr[i])
```

Te recomiendo el siguiente algoritmo:

- Buscar todos los OUTS
- Desde el final añades todos los elementos a un array solución hasta que tengas n-2*outs

Siendo n la longitud del array y outs el numero de "OUT" en el array

```
function henryParking(arr) {
    const outs=arr.reduce( (counter, current) => counter + (current=="OUT"?1:0), 0);
    const len=arr.length - 2*outs;
    let sol=new Array(len);
    let i = arr.length-1;
    let p=0;
    while(p<len){
        if(arr[i]!="OUT"){
            sol[len-p-1]=arr[i];
            p++;
        }
        i--;
    }
    return sol;
}
```